# Paste Excel worksheet to a PowerPoint presentation

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I'm attempting to paste from Excel to a finished PowerPoint presentation. I've taken bits of code from Peltier Tech and Spreadsheet Guru. The macro is intended to work within an Excel template that produces another Excel worksheet that would then paste into PowerPoint.

I've tested the code in the output worksheet itself and it works.

[image: Output when Macro works]

However, when the macro is executed for real in the Excel template it fails.

[image: Output when Macro fails]

Do I need to define the output worksheet as an object variable? And how do I reference that variable in the Excel to Powerpoint paste loop and MyRangeArray section?

Please note, objPPT is defined in a macro upstream of grandFinale().

```
Sub grandFinale()

Dim PPPres As PowerPoint.Presentation 
Dim PPSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim shp As Object
Dim MySlideArray As Variant
Dim MyRangeArray As Variant
Dim x As Long

Set objPPT = GetObject(, "Powerpoint.Application")
Set PPPres = objPPT.ActivePresentation
Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides(objPPT.ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.SlideIndex)

'declare pp slides
MySlideArray = Array(13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22)

'declare excel ranges
MyRangeArray = Array(Sheet2.Range("A6:C18"), Sheet2.Range("A21:C33"), _
    Sheet2.Range("A36:C48"), Sheet2.Range("A51:C63"), Sheet2.Range("A66:C78"), _
   Sheet2.Range("A81:C93"), Sheet2.Range("A96:C108"), Sheet2.Range("A111:C123"), Sheet2.Range("A126:C138"), Sheet2.Range("A141:C153"))

'excel to powerpoint paste loop
For x = LBound(MySlideArray) To UBound(MySlideArray)
MyRangeArray(x).Copy
Set shp = PPPres.Slides(MySlideArray(x)).Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=2)
'adjust images
With PPPres.PageSetup
    shp.Left = (.SlideWidth \ 2) - (shp.Width \ 2)
    shp.Top = (.SlideHeight \ 2) - (shp.Height \ 2)
End With

Next x
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Seems to me that right now you are copying from Sheet2 of the workbook containing the macro.  You don't show the code opening another (template) workbook, but I assume it's something like Set wk = Workbooks.Open("C:\test.xlsx").  If so, you would reference the sheet you want in that workbook with something like Set sh = wk.Worksheets("nameOfSheet") and then replace Sheet2 in your code with sh (After first defining the variables using Dim wk as Workbook, sh as Worksheet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original question lacks some details as to what the original worksheet is or does,
if it is in another workbook, and the macro is ran from that other workbook 
you must first create the new workbook with

```
dim wb as workbook
wb = application.workbooks.add
```

If the workbook is an existing workbook you use open instead

```
set wb =  workbooks.open("templateWB.xls")
```

to get to the specific sheet you need, if you just created a new workbook from scrap you could just use the first sheet:

```
dim ws as worksheet
ws =wb.worksheets(1)
```

or create one from scrap

```
dim ws as worksheet
set ws = wb.worksheets.add
```

the ws variable would be sent to your macro

```
grandFinale ws
```

you would then need to modify your sub to take a Worksheet as argument

```
Sub grandFinale(tempsheet as Worksheet)
```

in your code change all occurrences of Sheet2 for tempsheet or the variable name you use.

Comment: The original worksheet is in another Excel workbook and the macro runs from that workbook. The macro takes the original worksheet and performs a paste values into a new workbook and reformats the data with tasks like bolding text, changing fonts, merging cells, etc.  Sheet2 of the new workbook is 1 of 6 sheets.  @Tony M I used some old code made with record macro to open the new workbook so I'll have to declare it. I'll check back in with updates!

Comment: Thanks for the flow chart @jlucero, it was helping in getting the macro to work although I think "db" in the first line should read "wb". I used the Workbooks.Add method to open the new workbook and referenced that as an object in the MyRangeArray element of the macro above. I also deleted out a lot of record macro code and condensed the multi-macros of which grandFinale() was one into a single macro. That helped simplify things.